# THD analysis of an arbitrary expression in LTspice

Tags: ltspice, total-harmonic-distortion

Is it possible to perform `.four` THD analysis of *an arbitrary expression* in LTspice?

It works seamlessly with simple expressions like `V(out)` or `I(Rload)`, but I would like to perform THD analysis on an expression like `Ix(U1:VCC)+Ix(U1:VEE)`, which doesn't work (yields no output in the log) when I write

```
.tran 0 10m 0 1u
.four 1k 18 4 (Ix(U1:VCC)+Ix(U1:VEE))
```

Such an expression can easily be plotted, though.

[image]
[image]

Comment: I dont know about LTSpice and RMS THD but you can measure "peak distortion" by the asymmetry of an AC coupled signal. V+- V- which is just as meaningful and useful.

Comment: @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75 The difference won't show anything interesting, unfortunately. It looks more or less like `abs(sin(t))+c`, with some extra deviations.

Comment: Won't or doesn't?  Don't be so sure.   This one has 0.2%  asymmetry  which is probably close to the THD  http://tinyurl.com/swvre6c

Comment: @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75 Sorry, I don't get your point. In my circuit the buffer consumes some quiescent current from the top rail to the bottom, which is present on both pins, then positive output draws from the top rail [to the ground] and negative output draws from [the ground to] the bottom rail, so they _are_ asymmetrical, yes, but not in the sense you mean. See https://imgur.com/6PlxXwn

Comment: Or even better, see this: https://imgur.com/Mgmj130

Comment: Did you notice I was suggesting combined output voltage for asymmetry of the output voltage?  My plot shows the peaks , yours just shows the scale. Also I inserted DC offset to compensate for lower Vbe drop in 1st stage.  Not meant to duplicate your IC, but similar,.

Comment: @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75 I explained why subtracting currents here won't yield any useful results, but please, have a picture… https://imgur.com/a/i9nmMwv Subtracting voltages neither makes sense (because the power supply is ideal) nor is of interest for me.

Comment: I understand but you want to measure THD from current and I am saying how to measure it with peak voltage differential gain with DC offset removed (AC Coupled or offset nulled) then you say  there is no asym, for voltage? and talk about bipolar currents?

Comment: @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75 I do not want to study the impact of a non-ideal power supply in the circuit, and with an ideal supply the voltages at U1:Vcc and U1:Vee are _constant_. Thank you for your patience, but it seems it would take more than a comment to make me understand your idea.

Comment: Supply tolerance is not the issue. It is the difference in NPN/PNP Vbe vs Ic under load that results in the difference in +pk and-pk attenuation.  ?see the difference

Comment: @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75 There are resistances between the rails and voltage measurement points in your circuit, thus you _can_ reason about currents based on measured voltages. In _my_ circuit there are no resistances between the rails and the measurement points and the power supply has zero internal resistance, therefore I have no voltage alternation in the measurement points. Take a look at _my_ circuit, not yours. Anyway, I'd suggest not to analyse this post as an XY problem. I gave some context for the question, but that's it. To _discuss_ my circuit I'd have to use another site :)

Comment: The BUF634A uses a current sources for the driver rather than a fixed resistor , so the large swing THD should be much better.  These sources have resistance but are very high and the IC has no spec.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/102306/discussion-between-tony-stewart-sunnyskyguy-ee75-and-werediver).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mathematically I am not sure whether it is correct what you are trying to do. I suppose you should evaluate the THD of both supplies seperately. However, if you do want to do it in LTSpice, you may use some dummy resistors and an external current source.
[image: Schematic]

[image: Waveform]

In this example, the supply current difference is used as reference to bias another dummy resistor \$R_3\$, yielding:

\$THD_{R1}=43.3\%\$

\$THD_{R2}=47.16\%\$

\$THD_{R3}=0.03\%\$

Comment: That's a nice trick! Thank you very much for your time and effort.

Comment: Just be careful with the current direction of the resistors.